# Spark: should slaves have source code if already passed with ` --py-files` option?

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, pyspark

I have an ec2 cluster running pyspark application, I am passing the source doe with zipped python files while running `spark-submit` using `--py-files`. 
Do the slaves require the application code if we are passing the files already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the salves don't require the application code or zip file. The driver(master) where the spark job has been submitted only needs the zip file and source code(containing main method). The following things happen when client submit an spark job:

1. Driver program creates a physical execution plan from spark application code. The execution plan consists of stages and each stage contains several units those are called as tasks.
2. Cluster manager allocates resources and launches executors in workers(slaves) based on the client input.
3. With the proper monitoring by driver program, tasks are sent to executors and executors execute the tasks that has been assigned by driver program.
4. When main method exits or `stop()` method of sparkContext is called, cluster manager terminates all executors and deallocates all resources.

The whole execution is managed by driver program and cluster manager. Executors in the slaves depends on driver program for task execution. So the source code or zip file doesn't need to be copied or passed to slaves.
Here is the architecture how spark works:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html

https://www.dezyre.com/article/apache-spark-architecture-explained-in-detail/338